# volumetric shaders missing in blender 2.69

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I have installed blender 2.69 and it says that volumetric shaders will be supported but i cannot find them. Do i have to download then as an add on?

Answer (score 3):

Volumetrics have been added in 2.70, not 2.69.

Download the Release Candidate here: [blender.org/development/blender-2-70-release-candidate](http://blender.org/development/blender-2-70-release-candidate)

(A final stable version has not been released yet)

Answer (score 0):

Volimetric shading is in fact avaliable in Blender 2.69 but only in Blender Render renderer, not Cycles which got it in version 2.70.

There is a trick where you use composer to add volumetric shading to your image after having remainder rendered in Cycles renderer.